# Flexbox issue while aligning radio button

Tags: html, css, flexbox, radio-button

I am trying to align radio button and its label by making its parent element `display: flex;`.

However, when a radio button's `label` contains multiple lines, the radio button becomes narrower, even though its `width` is explicitly defined.[image: squeezed radio button]

Here is my html/css

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: 12px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-radios">
  <label>
 <input type="radio" /> Lorem ipsum.
  </label>
  <label>
 <input type="radio" /> Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum.
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the text content of `label` gets longer, it expands to fill more width, until the text uses 100% of available width and must start breaking lines. Since the default value of `flex-shrink` is 1, the `<input type="radio">`  *loses* width proportionately as the text grows, causing the radio button (or the apparent "margin" around it) to appear smaller. Or, if you have it custom styled as in your screenshot, squeezed.

To avoid that, add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `input`'s CSS rule, so it will not shrink from its default size even as its siblings take up all available room in their shared flexbox.

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: 12px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-radios">
  <label>
 <input type="radio" /> Lorem ipsum.
  </label>
  <label>
 <input type="radio" /> Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum..Lorem ipsum.
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Both the solutions are working like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Specify width for the input.

```css
.mg-radio{
display: flex;
}
.mg-radio input{
min-width: 30px;
height: 16px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="mg-radio">
    <input type="radio"  >
    <span class="radio-label" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate maxime debitis commodi totam, quia perspiciatis vel blanditiis iste sed tempore adipisci illum aperiam, obcaecati voluptatum mollitia natus at, neque nihil.</span>
  </label>
```

Comment: Did you try this then shrink the page size? It fails by shrinking the radio as opposed to squashing it, but still fails imo

Comment: changed to `min-width`. now it dosen't shrink.